# PS CS6 - Removing access colour behind a layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers, cs6

I'm trying to recreate the Google chrome logo and I've got to this stage, the issue is that the red colour is overlapping the outer ellipse where I've used the polygon lasso tool. I've managed to hide the overlapping on the inner ellipse by dragging the colour layer underneath the ellipse inner layer but I can't seem to work out how to to the same for the outer ellipse. Essentially I'm trying to make it so the colour stays in the contours of the outer ellipse:

[image]

The closest I've got so far is by moving the colour layer underneath both ellipse layers, which produces this:

[image]

However I'm not sure how to remove the access colour without also removing the colour underneath the outer ellipse.

Comment: Cut a hole in `Ellipse Outer` using `Ellipse Inner`, then place `RED` on top of `Ellipse Outer` and use a [clipping mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop-elements/using/clipping-masks.html). That said, logos should always be done with a vector application, like Illustrator for example.

Comment: Should title read Excess rather than Access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's a simple solution to this. Place the red layer directly above the grey outer elipse (as it is in your first screen shot). Right click on the red layer and select "create clipping mask". You should be able to repeat this with the blue and yellow layers once you've created those. Just add them above the red layer in the list and create a clipping mask for each one.

Comment: *repeat for the green and yellow layers I mean. The blue circle you can just place on top of your white inner elipse at the end

Comment: Hmm I've tried duplicating the red layer and rotating it around to form the next colour but it doesn't seem to want to work. I thought it would just pivot around but it seems to change shape. https://gyazo.com/32dd9d8a22daf5a59d872563d5150998

Comment: Oh never mind, I figured it out.